# Using onEdit trigger, is there a way to make sure the last row in a Sheet is visible to users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scroll

I have a Google Sheet that accumulates up to 100 entries per day. As users add new entries, the script puts new data into the last row (see snippet below). However, there are only 12 rows visible on the screen, so once those are filled, the user can't see new entries.

How can I make the last row visible to the user each time data is entered?

I am new to google-apps-script, so thanks for any ideas. I believe `onEdit` trigger no longer works with `sheet.setActiveRange()`, so I am looking for a work-around.  If there's no simple solution, I'll take a clunky one. For example, can a script be used to hide rows above the last row?

```js
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1' // Name of current sheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
    var dataCell = sheet.getRange('A1');
    var lastRowNumber = sheet.getDataRange().getNumRows();
    var newData = dataCell.getValue().split(",");
    var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();

    sheet.appendRow(newData);
```

Comment: How is the script called? And what makes you think `sheet.setActiveRange()` doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went back to my code and realized setActiveRange() does work with A1 notation inside the parenthesis. The bug must be in with how I used a variable for the range.  Taking a closer look now.

Comment: Can I use a variable inside the parenthesis? If so, is there a way to get the range of the newly appended row and assign that to a variable? In answer to your question, the script is bound to a Google Sheet and is triggered by editing cell A1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the newly added range by adding 1 to the lastrow and [activate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#activate()) it:

```
var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
sheet.appendRow(newData);
sheet.getRange("A" + (lastRow+1)).activate();//activate the newly appended row's A cell
```

Comment: Thanks! More concise than my solution (below).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution: setActiveRange(lastRow+2, lastColumn).  Scrolls down far enough, without the need to get the range of the appended row. Added advantage is it scrolls before the row is appended, so user sees data as it goes in.

```
function onEdit(e) { // Puts csv user data into Sheet1
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var SHEET_NAME = 'Sheet1' // Name of current sheet
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var dataCell = sheet.getRange('A1');
    var newData = dataCell.getValue().split(",");

     // Gets the address of the very last cell of this sheet
     var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
     var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

     // Scrolls to make sure user can see 2 rows below the current last cell
     var lastCell = sheet.getRange(lastRow+2, lastColumn);

    // Puts user entered data into a new row at the bottom of the spreadsheet
    sheet.appendRow(newData);
    sheet.setActiveRange(lastCell);
}
```